# iOS University Program on test Application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I am on a iOS University Program, and everything is registered OK, but on my computer I can not get this to work:s

I have generated the certificate from my computer, uploaded it and downloaded the certificate again. I am getting this error:

```
Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“CM2012”) were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

You should check apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1618/_index.html

Certificates is a tedious task in ios, but I recommend you to erase all certificates and follow the steps, it's the best way to get it.